# How to get email body content using Gmail API

Tags: java, email, gmail-api

I am using Gmail API to get email data in my simple Java application and I got everything whatever I want using [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) but I am unable to get full email content. I have used message.getRaw() but it returns null.
    So, anyone can help how can I access email content.

Comment: With email content, do you mean the text that is in the email? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **messages.list** to obtain identifiers of the messages, which will be used later to obtain *fully-qualified* messages separately via **messages.get**.

For some reason messages.list **ignores** fields that are set in request i.e. google sends back json that contains only default fields  `"messages(id,threadId),nextPageToken"`. That's why `message.getRaw()` returns `null`.

[api-explorer - gmail.users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/gmail.users.messages.list/m/gmail/v1/gmail.users.messages.list)

```
/**
 * Returns empty messages sent between after and before 
 * that contain only identifiers.
 * @param after
 * @param before
 * @param fields fields to be included in response 
 *               (IGNORED see api-explorer)  
 * @return 
 */
public List<Message> getEmptyMessages(Date after, Date before, String fields) {    
    Gmail.Users.Messages.List request = gmailService.users().messages().list("me")
             // or setQ("is:sent after:yyyy/MM/dd before:yyyy/MM/dd")
            .setLabelIds(Arrays.asList("SENT"))
            .setQ("after:" + gmailFormat(after) +" "+ 
                  "before:"+ gmailFormat(before))
            .setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS)
            .setFields(fields);

    List<Message> list = new LinkedList<>();
    ListMessagesResponse response = null;

    do {
       response = request.execute();
       list.addAll(response.getMessages());
       request.setPageToken(response.getNextPageToken());

    } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    return list;
}

public String gmailFormat(Date d) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    return sdf.format(d);
}
```

[api-explorer - gmail.users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/gmail.users.messages.get/m/gmail/v1/gmail.users.messages.get)

```
/**
 * Returns "fully-qualified" message.
 * @param id     identifier of the message to be obtained.
 * @param fields fields to be included in response e.g. "raw,snippet"
 *               (use api-explorer to build this string)
 * @return 
 */
public Message getFullyQualifiedMessage(String id, String fields) {
    return gmailService.users().messages().get("me", id)
            .setFormat("FULL")
            .setFields(fields)
            .execute();
}
```