# Get the full email body content using gmail api and android client

Tags: java, android, gmail, gmail-api

I need to get the full email body content using android client and gmail api. Following is the android code i have used to get email content

```
     String user = "me";
        List<String> messages=new ArrayList<>();
        ListMessagesResponse listresponse=mService.users().messages().list(user).execute();

        int a=0;
        for(Message message:listresponse.getMessages()){
            messages.add(message.getId());
            a++;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<=a;i++){
            Message message=mService.users().messages().get(user, messages.get(i)).setFormat("raw").execute();

            try {

                Log.d("Body", String.valueOf(message));

            }
            catch (Throwable t){
                Log.e("My app", "not done");
            }
        }

        return messages;

    }
```

Then i'm receiving the following output.

```
     D/Body: {"historyId":"******","id":"************","internalDate":"************","labelIds":["CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS","UNREAD","INBOX"],"raw":"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-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_WUVTPXRydWUmX3JpXz1YMEd6YzJYJTNEWVFwZ2xMakhKbFlRR283STRpcHpmNzIyemV6YmUzMHpncllqY1hjOWFzdXc2YW96Y
```

I'm having trouble with decoding the body content in this output. So what would be the mechanism that i have to follow to get the full body content? Thank you.

Comment: what part of the body are you exactly looking for? and what is the final goal that you are trying to achieve from this?

Comment: @SuyashGandhi - Need to extract full body content of the email. And i need to some NLP based function using those data

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964498/how-to-get-email-body-content-using-gmail-api) if it can help you. The answer here is in Java, but I think you can get the idea here on how to get the email body content.

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```java
String user = "me";
List<String> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
String query = "in:inbox";
ListMessagesResponse messageResponse =
        mService.users().messages().list(user).setQ(query).setMaxResults(Long.valueOf(6)).execute();

List<Message> messages = messageResponse.getMessages();

for (Message message : messages) {
    Message message2 = mService.users().messages().get(user, message.getId()).execute();

    //Get Body
    byte[] bodyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(message2.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getBody().getData().trim().toString()); // get body
    String body = new String(bodyBytes, "UTF-8");

    messageList.add(body);
    Log.d("bb", body);
}
```

Comment: Working solution but need to handle message2.getPayload().getParts() because sometimes its value is null.